# Echo certain value by AJAX request not working

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I've made an ajax call to the test.php and the call is even shown successful in the devtools `network`.
The problem is even after making a successful call the further `$country` is not been echoed.

Here is my code

**ajax.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interval</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$.ajax({url: 'test.php',
         data: {value: 'India'},
         type: 'post',
         success : function(data){
            alert(data);
         }     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] == 'India'){
     $country = $_POST['value'];
        echo $country;
}
?>
```

Comment: Remember, you use AJAX so you dont have to refresh the page. Make the PHP that is called by the javascript AJAX code a seperate file, then `echo $country;` and then get it in the js code from `success function(response){ alert($response);}`

Comment: Not working still there's no errors but it won't echo the output too.

Comment: Check out my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your ajax code and call that file from ajax. The reason why this is happening is because ajax.php is returning the whole page output starting from `<html>` and ending at `</html>`. So the ajax.php should look like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] == 'India'){
    $country = $_POST['value'];
    echo $country;
}
?>
```

Then your script can be edited to

```
<script>
$.ajax({url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {value: 'India'},
    type: 'post',
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }       
});
</script>
```

Comment: This means we cannot make the request to the same page?

Comment: You can, but it won't serve the purpose that you have in this use case.

Comment: Not working still there's no errors but it won't echo the output too.

Comment: I created a chatroom, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213494/echo-certain-value-by-ajax-request-not-working